# How to play video and audio synchronously from different sources?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10

I have separate video and audio URLs for the same media file and I want to play sound and video together synchronously. How can I do that?

I thought I can use a `MediaElement` and a `MediaPlayer` for video and audio:

```
mediaElement.Source = new Uri(videoSourceUrl, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
mediaPlayer.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromUri(new Uri(audioSourceUrl, 
                                               UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

But the problem is that there may be a delay in buffering in one of them, or user may change the position so video and audio not match.

Before I do stop and play and reposition manually, is there an easier way to join sound and video?

Comment: You will probably have to write all the decoding code yourself, to make sure buffers don't get out of sync, etc.

Comment: @downvoter any explanation on why you decided to down vote is much appreciated!

Comment: I don't know why you got a downvote :/ The only thing I can see wrong is that you haven't included your research so far. But the actual question itself is interesting, to me at least, and it doesn't seem badly presented.

Comment: @AndyJ agreed and upvoted. Back to '0' again :P

Comment: Because the streams are independent, you have to define "synchronously". Are the video and audio tracks guaranteed to be the same length? If so, you could use that metric to buffer one any time the other is buffering, and start playing them at the same time stamp when you've filled the buffer enough.

Comment: @Blendester Also, what does "hardcode" mean? Please explain that further; it's too vague.

Comment: @MageshKumaar Thanks.. it feels better now :)

Comment: No matter what, your solution will include buffering both the audio and the video before you do anything else.  Otherwise, just the time it takes to retrieve from the URLs would be enough to throw you out of sync.

Comment: @MickyD I edited, I hope now it is better

Comment: @Dan yes it's a YouTube video, but sound and video come from different urls. it's for the same media file.

Comment: @MickyD It's a shame it's so hard to get people to comment when they downvote. Then we wouldn't have to play the guessing games ... oh well.

Comment: @Blendester Thank-you for the clarification.  I see no problem now with your fine question. Good luck +1

Comment: @AndyJ Agreed. Some people don't for fear of retaliation.  I don't care about that sort of thing anymore.  By the way I did downvote and comment (which I just rolled back due to the OP's recent edit).  Dunno who the other dud was :)

Comment: Unfortunately, this feels too complicated to be answered in a single question. There is no out-of-box solution, at least as far as I know. The only thing I can think of is downloading both sources and mixing them with, let's say, ffmpeg, then playing the whole thing. You did say "play", not "stream" after all :)

Comment: @MickyD Good to know some people use SO correctly!